# Separate Python web scraped data in different columns (Excel)

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, multiple-columns, export-to-csv

Dear Stackoverflow community,

Recently I started playing around with Python. I learned a lot watching YouTube videos and browsing this platform. But I can't solve my problem.

Hope you guys can help me out.

So I tried to scrape information from websites using Python(Anaconda). And put this information in an CSV file. I tried to separate the columns by adding "," in my script. But when I open my CSV file all the data is put together in 1 column(A). Instead I want the data to be separated in different columns(A & B (and C, D, E, F etc when I want to add info)).

What do I have to add into this code:

```
filename = "brands.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, shipping\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    brand_container = container.findAll("h2",{"class":"product-name"})
    brand = brand_container[0].a.text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("p",{"class":"availability in-stock"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("shipping: " + shipping)

    f.write(brand + "," + shipping +  "," + "\n")

f.close()
```

Thank you for helping out!

Kind regards,

---

Complete script after Game0ver's suggestion:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.scraped-website.com'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")   

# grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"item last"})
container = containers[0]

import csv

filename = "brands.csv"
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['brand', 'shipping']
    # define your delimiter
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

for container in containers:
    brand_container = container.findAll("h2",{"class":"product-name"})
    brand = brand_container[0].a.text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("p",{"class":"availability in-stock"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("shipping: " + shipping)
```

As I mentioned this code didn't work. I must have done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You better use [python's csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) to do that:

```
import csv

filename = "brands.csv"
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['brand', 'shipping']
    # define your delimiter
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    # write rows...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to use this solution but as a result the CSV file only showed 'brand, shipping' in the first column. I didn't even got back my information in the other rows. But maybe I made the mistake in the coding. Is this how it is supposed to look like:

Comment: ... = containers[0]

import csv

filename = "brands.csv"
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['brand', 'shipping']
    # define your delimiter
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

for container in containers:
 brand_container = container.findAll("h2",{"class":"product-name"})
 brand = brand_container[0].a.text

 shipping_container = container.findAll("p",{"class":"availability in-stock"})
 shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

 print("brand: " + brand)
 print("shipping: " + shipping)

Comment: You have to use [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) method to write rows to your csv. Also if you have any issues it would be better to update your question with your current code in order to be more easy for me to test it.

Comment: I have completed the edited script. I must have done something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you actually never write your rows to csv. For every row, you need to use `writer.writerow(your_row_here)`, that's why your csv is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your values in double quotes, like

```
f.write('"'+brand + '","' + shipping +  '"\n')
```

Although, there are more better ways to handle this generic task and this functionality.

Comment: I deleted my line (f.write(brand + "," + shipping +  "," + "\n")) and replaced it with yours. Unfortunately it didn't work. Instead of 1 comma it only added a few quotes as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose either of the ways I've shown below. As the url avaiable within your script is unreachable, I've provided a working one.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://yts.am/browse-movies"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

with open("movieinfo.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['name', 'year'])
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in soup.select(".browse-movie-bottom"):
        d = {}
        d['name'] = row.select_one(".browse-movie-title").text
        d['year'] = row.select_one(".browse-movie-year").text
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Or you can try like the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

with open("movieinfo.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['name','year'])

    for row in soup.select(".browse-movie-bottom"):
        name = row.select_one(".browse-movie-title").text
        year = row.select_one(".browse-movie-year").text
        writer.writerow([name,year])
```